# Socket explanation in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Well I have been wondering if there is a standard socket header file for C++

I did search the whole internet (using google search engine ), but couldn't find any standard socket header file for C++ , beside finding some libraries, like Boost, chilkat etc...

I have only succeeded in finding a standard socket header file for C programming language. 
If I used the C standard socket header file, but inside my C++ code, does it mean my program 
is Pure C++ or C and C++?

Because I didn't find any standard C++ socket header file. Like 
there is `<string>` for C++ and there is `<string.h>` for C, but there is no socket 
standard header file for C++.

I hope someone C/C++ wise would explain all that for me, step by step.

Comment: Why should your code be c code only because you use c headers and which standard socket header are you using? Usually sockets depend on your operating system.

Comment: that why i'm asking, to get explain and understand it

Comment: There is no such thing as a C and C++ source file. If you compile it with a C++ compiler, it was (interpreted as) a C++ source file; if you compile it with a C compiler, it was (interpreted as) a C source file. *With great care*, you can mix object files created with different compilers to obtain a single executable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard socket library in C++. You can either use whatever sockets API your operating system provides (typically a C API, on Unix operating systems it would be the [BSD sockets API](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~jms/socket-info.html)), or you can use a C++ library like [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), which is cross-platform.

Comment: I didn't get my answers, does using the standard socket header file for C inside my C++ app, makes it c and c++? or just C++?

Comment: @user1341993, there *is* no standard socket header in either C or C++.

Comment: Typically the header file or your code provides syntactic sugar that enables it to be used OK within a C++ program, `extern 'C'`, per http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: @user1341993: If you use a C sockets API in your C++ program (note that there is no *standard* one), it's still a C++ program. The *style* of the code might be C-like, which may or may not bother you, but it will still be a C++ program.

Answer (score 2):

[BSD sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), invented by Bill Joy back in the 70's, is arguably the "standard sockets API".

Typically, you'd include the following headers:

```
#include <sys/socket.h> // Core BSD socket functions and data structures.
#include <netinet/in.h> // AF_INET and AF_INET6 address families and their
                        // corresponding protocol families PF_INET and PF_INET6.
#include <arpa/inet.h>  // Functions for manipulating numeric IP addresses.
#include <netdb.h>      // Name resolution
```

Beej's Guide is an excellent tutorial on sockets (BSD sockets) programming:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score 0):

If you include c header files but compile your code using c++ then it will produce a c++ app.
There are numerous c++ frameworks such as Boost::asio, ACE, WinSock etc.. that you can use. It depends if you want your code to be portable and if your application is only ever going to be run on a particular OS, ie. Linux, Mac or Windows.

Also as C++ is a superset of C it is irrelevant whether you use C or C++ because you are compiling a C++ program so you generate C++ pure and simple.